# How do I make a .NET Core 6 Top-Level statement template async?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm follwoing this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration and I don't understand how to make my application work as an async Main method.

```
using IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
     .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, configuration) =>
     {
         configuration.Sources.Clear();
         ILogger logger = NullLogger.Instance;

         IHostEnvironment env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

         configuration
             .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
             .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true, true);

         IConfigurationRoot configurationRoot = configuration.Build();
         ApiConfig options = new();
         configurationRoot.GetSection(nameof(ApiConfig)).Bind(options);
         
         var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
         serviceCollection.AddHttpClient();
         serviceCollection.AddMemoryCache();
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IMyClient, MyClient>();
         IServiceProvider provider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

         IHttpClientFactory clientFactory = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();

     })
    .Build();

// Application code should start here.
     Result result = await myClient. Get(ApiConfig);
// If i put it here, the client is not available since its inside the //ConfigureAppConfiguration.
```

If I put the client inside the ConfigureAppConfiguration, is fails saying: The await operator can only be used within an async labmda expression.
How do I make my console app to be async?

Now I want to instantiate MyClient, and use it to make query, however, since its need so to await the result, I fails. I don't understand how to make the app async. How should I solve this?

Comment: This is nothing to do with `await`, it's because you haven't instantiated a new `myClient` object. You need to get one by doing `var myClient = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IMyService>();`

Comment: @DavidG how do i reach my options (ApiConfig) which i want to pass to the client on the Get call?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: I think you need to generally have a read about dependency injection and understand how that works.

Comment: @DavidG , i was a bit quick; the var myClient = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IMyService>(); does not work. It just throws exception ": 'No service for type 'MyClinet' has been registered". How come its not registered?

Comment: Sure, we can educate over a single specific thing, but when it comes to the bigger picture of learning, you need to spend some effort advancing your own skills. See, you asked one question which I answered, and now you have moved on to a second and third questions. Not only is it quicker for you to go and learn like I suggested, it's better for you in the long run.

Comment: I wathced this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdhFw1VSowg&ab_channel=IAmTimCorey and here services are added like builder. Services.Add......(); Why cant i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i found the problem, i copied the .net 6 code example into a     net5.0 existing application. After i recreated everything  targeting .net 6, things work as expected.